# Oracle DB - Connection Issue

Tags: database, oracle, client

I am not a Oracle DB expert.

I need to connect to a REMOTE Oracle 19c database server from VDI through Oracle Client or SQL*PLUS.

I only have the Database Name "Orcl" and the TNS Connect string "dev1".

1. Please advise what are all the pre-requisites that I need to have in my VDI, so I can connect to the remote DB.
2. What are the environmental variable I need to set in my VDI ?
3. Do I need to have Oracle client installed in my machine ? which version of Oracle client ?
4. If I have Oracle 12c client in my machine, will I be able to connect to Oracle 19C DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the vdi plays into it at all.  You will be making a connection across a network interface (even if the client and database are on the same machine).  Yes you will need an oracle client.  I think a 12c client is the oldest client that is still certified for connection to 19c database. To be sure Refer to Oracle Support Document 207303.1.  For the client, using a network connection, I believe the only environment variable required is ORACLE_HOME.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very much helpful.